# Use of tables not referenced in a model :join_table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is is possible to do? I'm kinda lost with this.

I'm trying to add some functionality to a Ruby on Rails 3.2 app that I did not develop but I am confused with the model definitions.

Here is and example:

```
    class Indicator < ActiveRecord::Base
      #attr_accessible :name, :objective_ids, :weight, :operation_id, :objective_id,         :unit, :formula, :acronym
      attr_protected
      has_and_belongs_to_many :objectives
    
      has_many :indicator_scores
      has_many :indicatorscores, :class_name => 'IndicatorScore', :foreign_key =>         "scoredate_id"
      belongs_to :operation

      belongs_to :objective

      has_and_belongs_to_many :sons, :join_table => "indicator_father_son",    :class_name => "Indicator", :foreign_key => "indicatorfather_id", :association_foreign_key => "indicatorson_id"


    end
```

In this Model, specially on the **has_and_belongs_to_many** option I have crossed thoughts because the table  **"indicator_father_son"** doesn't have a model.

Is this legal in Ruby on Rails MVC convention?

What does the **has_and_belongs_to_many** clause with all the options exactly do? and why is it necessary?

I can provide more code if the model show is not enough to grasp the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

"A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many connection with another model, with no intervening model. For example, if your application includes assemblies and parts, with each assembly having many parts and each part appearing in many assemblies, you could declare the models this way."

In this case, the original coder added a :join_table clause that forces the table name to match the specified value.  If you open up your database, you will see a table named indicator_father_son.

Similarly, the foreign_key and association_foreign_key overrides the default foreign key names.